# Magento 2 get current store currency code

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-id

In Magento 2 I have tried to get the current store code by the below-mentioned code line. But it returns an empty string.

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: In which file do you need this code? Custom module ?

Comment: Yes its in custom module.

Comment: And ive called Store Manager properly there 

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Yes that didn't work for me

Comment: both the solution didn't work?

Comment: **$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode()** This worked

Comment: Ok mate happy coding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following code,

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode()
```

(Or)

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
) {           
  $this->_priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
}

public function getCurrentCurrencyCode()
{
  return $this->_priceCurrency->getCurrency()->getCurrencyCode();
}
```

And call this function from your template,

```
echo $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

Comment: **$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode()**

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

To get store code:

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
```

After your question update, to get current currency code

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode(); //EUR
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: to get the `store code` as you asked, it should work

Comment: Just I needed to get currency code dude

Comment: Look your post title and content before update, at no time you are talking about `currency`